# Will docker cost system resources to exchange data with system?

Tags: docker

In docker, we can use -v params mapping system directory to the directory in the docker. Like:

```
docker run -d -v /data:/data
```

Will it cost obviously more time compare with read file in system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the two outputs of the command (ran only two times, with very close results):

```
$time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/rm bs=8k count=200000 && sync"
```

On my host:

```
1638400000 bytes (1.6 GB) copied, 17.3344 s, 94.5 MB/s
sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/rm bs=8k count=200000 && sync"
0.06s user
1.62s system
```

In a container:

```
1638400000 bytes (1.6 GB) copied, 17.586 s, 93.2 MB/s

user    0m0.052s
sys     0m1.852s
```

So the answer is no, there is not any obvious additional cost on HDD access (and there shouldn't, thanks to containerization).